# How to store object of NSObject Class using File Archiving

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject, nskeyedarchiver

I am trying to store an object of NSObject Class using file archiving. When i tried

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:myObject toFile:@"filePath"];
```

and

```
NSArray *myArray=@[myObject];
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:myObject toFile:@"FilePath"];
```

But both returns warning !!

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ePub encodeWithCoder:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xeac3570'

Comment: And the warning is...?

Comment: @CRD I have added the warning

Answer (score 1):

You need to put encodeWithCoder and Decoder in your NSObject :

in your header :

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
```

in your .m

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
    [coder encodeObject:self.yourProperty forKey:@"yourProperty"];
}



- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {

        self.yourProperty = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"yourProperty"];


    }
    return self;
}
```

you need to do that for all properties.

Note that for other types, like integers and floats, use decodeIntForKey and EncodeInt accordingly.